# Write into file from assets folder uwp

Tags: win-universal-app

I'd like to write text content into a file that is located `Assets` folder, so I access file but I don't have access to write into it, my code is:

```
    try {
            //get the file
            StorageFile storageFile = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri("ms-appx:///assets/test.txt"));

            //try to write sring to it
            await FileIO.WriteTextAsync(storageFile, "my string");

            } catch (Exception ex) {
            Debug.WriteLine("error: " + ex);

            }
```

and I get the error:

```
    Exception thrown: 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' in mscorlib.ni.dll
error: System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at MyProject.MainPage.<overWriteHtmlSrcFile>d__6.MoveNext()
```

Have to mention that I need to change this file due app scenario, or maybe is there a way to create this file in public app folder and then move it in assets.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Files located into `Assets` folder are `read only` that's why you get this exception. Like you mentioned at the end, there is a method to create your file in a public location, write what you need into it and then just move the file in assets folder. It will be like:

```
 try {
            //create file in public folder
            StorageFolder storageFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
            StorageFile sampleFile = await storageFolder.CreateFileAsync("test.txt", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

            //write sring to created file
            await FileIO.WriteTextAsync(sampleFile, htmlSrc);

            //get asets folder
            StorageFolder appInstalledFolder = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation;
            StorageFolder assetsFolder = await appInstalledFolder.GetFolderAsync("Assets");

            //move file from public folder to assets
            await sampleFile.MoveAsync(assetsFolder, "new_file_name.txt", NameCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

            } catch (Exception ex) {
            Debug.WriteLine("error: " + ex);

            }
```