# UWP: allow XSL transformation in a WebView for local content

Tags: xml, xslt, webview, uwp, microsoft-edge

I want to display a local XML file on a `WebView`. The XML file references a local XSL file (in the same folder). But the stylesheet is not applied and the reason for this seems to be security concerns.

If I open the file in the console of Edge I get

> XSLT8690: The system cannot locate the object specified.

Is there a possibility to allow the XSL transformation of a local file (e.g. like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10567546/426227))? How can I display a local XML file, which references a stylesheet?

Comment: Where did you put the XML and XSL file? I put them under application's assets folder and it works well.

Comment: Yes, the assets folder does work. I want to put it in any other folder e.g. `TempState`, `LocalCache` and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your XML and XSL file are not in application's assets folder, then setting the [WebView.Navigate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.navigate.aspx) method or [WebView.Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.source.aspx) property to the XML file will not work. To solve this issue, we can use [XsltProcessor class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.data.xml.xsl.xsltprocessor.aspx) to transform xml according to the style sheet declaration specified in xslt file first and then using [WebView.NavigateToString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.navigatetostring.aspx) method to load the transformed HTML content.

For example:

```cs
var xmlFile = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalCacheFolder.GetFileAsync("test.xml");
var xsltFile = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalCacheFolder.GetFileAsync("test.xsl");

var doc = await Windows.Data.Xml.Dom.XmlDocument.LoadFromFileAsync(xmlFile);
var xsltDoc = await Windows.Data.Xml.Dom.XmlDocument.LoadFromFileAsync(xsltFile);

// Transform xml according to the style sheet declaration specified in xslt file
var xsltProcessor = new Windows.Data.Xml.Xsl.XsltProcessor(xsltDoc);
var transformedStr = xsltProcessor.TransformToString(doc);

//MyWebView is the WebView control in XAML
MyWebView.NavigateToString(transformedStr);
```

---

**Update:**

> I get *Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component. at Windows.Data.Xml.Xsl.XsltProcessor.TransformToString(IXmlNod‌​e inputNode).*

The problem here is that in your example's XSL file, it is using XSLT `document()` function. However for security reasons, execution of the `document()` function was prohibited in UWP. So you get the error when executing `XsltProcessor.TransformToString` method.

For classic .NET Framework apps, we can set [XsltSettings.EnableDocumentFunction Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xsl.xsltsettings.enabledocumentfunction(v=vs.110).aspx) to enable support for the XSLT `document()` function. However there is no such class or property in UWP. You are welcome to submit a request for this feature through [**UserVoice**](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-universal-windows-platform).

And for your specific XSL file, it only used `document()` function in two place:

```
<xsl:if test="$useexternalcss=1">
  <style type="text/css" media="screen">
    <xsl:value-of select="document($externalcssname)" />
  </style>
</xsl:if>
...
<p class="subtitle_create">
  <xsl:text>Angezeigt mit </xsl:text>
  <xsl:value-of select="document('')/xsl:stylesheet/@id" />
</p>
```

For the first place, as it didn't use external css, so the `document()` function won't execute. We can ignore it or comment out it for sure. And in the second place, `document()` function is used to get the `stylesheet`'s `id` which is *"ELGA_Referenzstylesheet_1.04.009.1"* and I think this value is a constant. It won't change if the stylesheet didn't change. So I think you can change it like following:

```
<p class="subtitle_create">
  <xsl:text>Angezeigt mit </xsl:text>
  <xsl:text>ELGA_Referenzstylesheet_1.04.009.1</xsl:text>
</p>
```

After this, you can retry with `XsltProcessor.TransformToString` method, it should be able to work.

Comment: I get *Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component. at Windows.Data.Xml.Xsl.XsltProcessor.TransformToString(IXmlNode inputNode)*.

Comment: @testing What's the xml and xsl file you are using? I'm testing with [the code here](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/tryxslt.asp?xmlfile=cdcatalog&xsltfile=cdcatalog) and it works well.

Comment: Take *ELGA-023-Entlassungsbrief_aerztlich_EIS-FullSupport.xml* from [these examples](https://www.elga.gv.at/fileadmin/user_upload/Dokumente_PDF_MP4/CDA/Beispieldokumente_2.06.1/Beispieldokumente_2.06.1.zip).

Comment: @testing Yeah I can reproduce your issue. The problem here is related to the XSLT document() function.  Please check my updated answer.

Comment: I'm glad you figured it out, what the reason is. The linked xml document is only an example, demonstrating all of the features a document of this type can support, according to the norm. There are different types of xml documents and all of them should be supported. That means in real use cases I don't know, when the `document()` function is used and when not. I can filter through known cases as you demonstrated this. But that wouldn't be a robust solution. My best bet would be to use your approach with the `XsltProcessor` and use for example the Javascript fallback. Or any other idea?

Comment: I've filled a [feature request](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-universal-windows-platform/suggestions/16933771-enabledocumentfunction-property-to-allow-document) to speed up the process. This would be the solution I need in this case!

Answer (score 0):

Possible options, which comes to my mind:

- use another browser
- use a local webserver
- put the xml and xsl file onto a webserver and access the URL only (let the webserver make the transformation)
- use XSLT transformation in browser via Javascript ([xslt.js](http://johannburkard.de/software/xsltjs/), [Saxon-CE](http://www.saxonica.com/ce/index.xml), [Magic XML](http://tomdavies.azurewebsites.net/magicxml/#examples), [Google ajaxslt](https://code.google.com/archive/p/ajaxslt/), [Sarissa](https://sourceforge.net/projects/sarissa/) or even a [custom solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5722410/how-can-i-use-javascript-to-transform-xml-xslt))
- use [Libxslt](https://www.nuget.org/packages/libxslt/) library

The disadvantage of the browser method is, that all libraries are outdated and the existing ones do not support all features for the transformation. Implementations can be found [here](http://ivanz.com/2011/05/12/client-side-xslt-transformations-with-javascript/) and [here](http://ajaxandxml.blogspot.co.at/2007/07/example-use-xslt-transformation-in.html). There are also some jQuery wrapper available (see [[1]](https://github.com/hyperthunk/jquery.xslt), [[2]](https://github.com/purtuga/jquery.transform) or [[3]](https://github.com/jvverde/XSLT)).

There is also a [feature request](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/257854-microsoft-edge-developer/suggestions/12798480-support-xml-transformation-with-xslt-from-file) for the webview.

[Copying the xml file to the asset folder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35937233/426227), doesn't work. A blank, white page is displayed here. But it works, if you use a file from the asset folder, which you include before compile time.